# How to remove fieldname "type" from salesforce output payload in mule 4

Tags: salesforce, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am using Salesforce "Query" connect to fetch data in Mule 4. However, the output payload is displaying an additional field called type (which displays ObjectName). Is there any way to avoid fetching/displaying this field?

Input query passing to Salesforce: "Select AccountNumber,Name,Id from Account"

Output: As can see, I don't want the "type" to be displayed.

```
 [
  {
    "Id": "0012x0000054TjZAAU",
    **"type": "Account"**,
    "AccountNumber": "CD355120-B",
    "Name": "United Oil & Gas, Singapore"
  },
  {
    "Id": "0012x0000054TjUAAU",
    **"type": "Account"**,
    "AccountNumber": "CD439877",
    "Name": "Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd"
  }
]
```

Expected Output: Without "Type" in output.

```
 [
  {
    "Id": "0012x0000054TjZAAU",
    "AccountNumber": "CD355120-B",
    "Name": "United Oil & Gas, Singapore"
  },
  {
    "Id": "0012x0000054TjUAAU",
    "AccountNumber": "CD439877",
    "Name": "Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

Map over each item and remove the field

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map $ - "type"
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "0012x0000054TjZAAU",
    "AccountNumber": "CD355120-B",
    "Name": "United Oil & Gas, Singapore"
  },
  {
    "Id": "0012x0000054TjUAAU",
    "AccountNumber": "CD439877",
    "Name": "Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd"
  }
]
```